# PostgreSQL: Returning ordered rows after a specific ID

Tags: postgresql

**Scenario:**
I am displaying a table of records. It initially displays the first 500 with "show more" at the bottom, which returns the next 500.

**Issue:**
If between initial display and clicking "show more" 1 record is added, that will cause "order by date, offset 500, limit 500" to overlap by 1 row.

I'd like to "order by date, offset until 'id of last row shown', limit 500"

My row IDs are UUIDs. I am open to alternative approaches that achieve the same result.

Comment: @Lashane Why is showing duplicate data to a user that has expectations of unique data a problem?

Comment: yes, why it is a problem? it is multi-user environment, so user should see all updates from others

Comment: Say the limit was 5 and 1 row was added before show more was pressed, the user would see "A, B, C, D, E, E, F, G, H, I" Note the double E. The effect becomes worse with increased update speed or smaller limits.

Comment: I understand effect, why do you think that it is problem?

Comment: Lets make pretend this is a patients medication history. This could show them as receiving medication twice when they really received it once. Some one is now dead because of this error.

Comment: If the only column you have to order on is a date then the paging will be wrong even if the table suffers no alterations.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Would that be resolved if it was ordered by date, then by id?

Comment: If the id is not sequential that would fix the static table paging, but not the altering one.

Answer (score 3):

i think you can use a subquery in the where to accomplish this.

e.g. given you're paginating through a `users` table, and you want the records after a given user:

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
  WHERE created_at > (
    SELECT created_at
      FROM users
      WHERE users.id = '00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444'
      LIMIT 1
  )
  ORDER BY created_at DESC limit 5;
```

Comment: Won't work if dates are not unique, which can happen in case of batch inserts.

Answer (score 2):

If you can order by ID, you can paginate using

```
where id > $last_seen_id limit 500
```

but that's not going to be useful where you're sorting by `date`.

### Sort stability!

I really hope that "date" actually means "timestamp" though, otherwise your ordering will be unstable and you can miss rows in pagination; you'll have to order by `date, id` to get stable ordering if it's really a `date`, and should probably do so even for `timestamp`.

### State on client

One option is to push the state out to the client. Have the client remember the last-seen (date,id) tuple, and use:

```
where date > $last_seen_date and id > $last_seen_id limit 500
```

### Cursors

Do you care about scalability? If not, you can use a server-side cursor. Declare the cursor for the full query, without the `LIMIT`. Then `FETCH` chunks of rows as requested. To do this your app must have a way to consistently bind a connection to a specific user's requests, though, and not to reset that connection or return it to the pool between requests. This might not be practical with your pool/framework, but is probably the best solution if you can do it.

### Temp tables

Another even less scalable option is to `CREATE TABLE sessiondata.myuser_myrequest_blah AS SELECT ....` then paginate *that* table. It's guaranteed not to change. This avoids the difficulty of needing to keep a consistent connection across requests, but will have a very slow first-request response time and is completely impractical for large user counts or large amounts of data.

### Related questions

- [Handling paging with changing sort orders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26188519/398670)
- [Using "Cursors" for paging in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13142834/398670)
- [How to provide an API client with 1,000,000 database results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13144005/398670)