# postgresql select next 10 after something

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Is there any way to select the next 10 rows after the row with ID where rows are ordered by something.

I've come up only with simple solution like:

1. select all
2. apply a loop to find ID and then return next 10

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use LIMIT . See the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-limit.html):

```
SELECT * from tableName
WHERE id > yourID
ORDER BY ID ASC
LIMIT NumRows
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/68ad4/3)</kbd>

If the rows aren't orderd by ID, you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1
WHERE orderColumn > (
  SELECT orderColumn from tab1
  WHERE id = YourId
)
ORDER BY orderColumn
LIMIT 10
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/51652/1)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, thanks! But the problem is I don't know the RowToStart. I just know its ID

Comment: +1: nice! I'm not too experienced with postgres, but my intuition says this problem could be even better solved by using cursors (given the plan for this query). Do you know about that?

Comment: I wouldnt use them, but there are some discussions around here about using them for something like this. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13142834/1385896)

Comment: Cool, thank you for this solution! There still is a little problem: what if orderColumn is not unique?

Comment: @typedef You can do >= that select and put id <> yourid in the outside where